# How to prevent form submit on enter key press using angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="toggleForm()">Add translation</button>
<form class="block form-inline" id="translation_form" ng-show="form" ng-submit="addTranslation()">
    <h4>
        Enter a new translation for this text in {{language | uppercase}}:
        <button class="close" ng-click="toggleForm()" title="Close form">&times;</button>
    </h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.text" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$scope.formData = {
    text: ''
};

$scope.toggleForm = function()
{
    if ($scope.form)
    {
        console.log('form closed', $scope.formData.text);
        $scope.form = false;
        $scope.formData.text = '';
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.form = true;

        if ($scope.history
            && ($scope.history.length > 0))
        {
            // set some default text
            $scope.formData.text = $scope.history[0].translation;
        }

        console.log('form opened', $scope.formData.text);
    }
};

$scope.addTranslation = function()
{
    console.log('adding translation', $scope.formData.text);
    // ajax call to post the text
    callback = function()
    {
        $scope.form = false;
        $scope.formData.text = '';
    }
};
```

The problem:
when I open the form, type some text and click on the "Add" button, the following texts are logged in the console:

```
form opened {some text here}
adding translation {some text here}
```

BUT if I open the form and tap Enter while focused on the input field, the following is logged:

```
form opened {some text here}
form closed {some text here}
adding translation {NO text here, because toggleForm empties the variable}
```

Obviously, this is a problem, since I want to be able to submit the form by tapping Enter aswell.
The question is - why is this happening and how to prevent it?

---

Edit: avoided the problem by changing the HTML structure to the following:

```
<div class="block" ng-show="form">
    <h4>
        Enter a new translation for this text in {{language | uppercase}}:
        <button class="close" ng-click="toggleForm()" title="Close form">&times;</button>
    </h4>
    <hr />
    <form class="form-inline" id="translation_form" ng-submit="addTranslation()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.text" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

However, I still have no answer as to why AngularJS even called the close button's onclick event in the first place...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This response is a little late, but this issue just tripped my team up this afternoon - hopefully our experience will help others.

Merely adding attribute `type="button"` to your button object will do the trick - no need for any other changes.  This is actually a good attribute to add to any button on your form that is not expressly a form submit button.

```
<button class="close" type="button" ng-click="toggleForm()" title="Close form">&times;</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, I found this out a long time ago too. Never set that attribute to `button` before that, so...

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `'type="submit"'` from the add button and use `ng-click="addTranslation()"` instead. Also remove `ng-submit` from the `form` tag as follows

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="toggleForm()">Add translation</button>
<form class="block form-inline" id="translation_form" ng-show="form">
    <h4>
        Enter a new translation for this text in {{language | uppercase}}:
        <button class="close" ng-click="toggleForm()" title="Close form">&times;</button>
    </h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.text" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="addTranslation()">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is probably your best bet since "submit" buttons will ALWAYS respond to pressing the Enter key. Also, if you do not specify the "type" attribute for a button, some browsers think it is "button" while some think it is "submit". Always specify the "type" attribute on a button.

Comment: That's not really a solution because, as I said, I want to be able to submit the form using the Enter key. The question is why does AngularJS trigger the on-click event for the button in the first place? It shouldn't do that, it's not logical.

Comment: @jurchiks This is logical and makes sense. Please read the first comment. If you have a button type of 'submit' in your html, then the enter key will trigger the action on the submit button(This is nothing to do with AngularJS).

Comment: @Mathews - no, it isn't. I am not clicking on the button, I am submitting the form via Enter. The only thing that should trigger is `form.submit` and its equivalents. Anyway, I changed the structure a bit, as can be seen in my question, and MBielski answered the question anyway. Some stupid legacy logic there, I bet.